# Open a .docx file with Office Online

Tags: microsoft-office, google-docs

With Google Drive they have complimentary products like Google Docs that opens the web editor when you double click it on your desktop. Is there a way to set that up with .docx files and Office Online. I want to be able to double-click my .docx file and have my web browser open it in Office Online like how Google Docs does.

Comment: Yes, it is called OneDrive. You install it, it syncs all your document online, then you go to the OneDrive web site and open the document there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [shortcut that sends the file to OneDrive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141215174835/http://www.howtogeek.com/194150/how-to-add-onedrive-to-the-send-to-context-menu-in-windows-7-or-8.1/).

Once it is in OneDrive, you can edit it.